# No Forward Slash on URL redirects back to Homepage

Tags: magento-1.9, redirect, htaccess

We've got a strange issue with a Magento 1.9 install where any page that you try and navigate to that doesn't have a slash on the end of the URL is automatically redirect back to the homepage.

Our default 404 page is the homepage.

This is what we have in the .htaccess, can anyone shed any light on this.

```
############################################
## uncomment these lines for CGI mode
## make sure to specify the correct cgi php binary file name
## it might be /cgi-bin/php-cgi

#    Action php5-cgi /cgi-bin/php5-cgi
#    AddHandler php5-cgi .php

############################################
## GoDaddy specific options

#   Options -MultiViews

## you might also need to add this line to php.ini
##     cgi.fix_pathinfo = 1
## if it still doesn't work, rename php.ini to php5.ini

############################################
## this line is specific for 1and1 hosting

    #AddType x-mapp-php5 .php
    #AddHandler x-mapp-php5 .php

############################################
## default index file

    DirectoryIndex index.php

<IfModule mod_php5.c>

############################################
## adjust memory limit

    php_value memory_limit 512M
    php_value upload_max_filesize 64M
    php_value post_max_size 64M
    php_value max_execution_time 360000

############################################
## disable magic quotes for php request vars

    php_flag magic_quotes_gpc off

############################################
## disable automatic session start
## before autoload was initialized

    php_flag session.auto_start off

############################################
## enable resulting html compression

    #php_flag zlib.output_compression on

###########################################
# disable user agent verification to not break multiple image upload

    php_flag suhosin.session.cryptua off

###########################################
# turn off compatibility with PHP4 when dealing with objects

    php_flag zend.ze1_compatibility_mode Off

</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_security.c>
###########################################
# disable POST processing to not break multiple image upload

    SecFilterEngine Off
    SecFilterScanPOST Off
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_deflate.c>

############################################
## enable apache served files compression
## http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#gzip

    # Insert filter on all content
    ###SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
    # Insert filter on selected content types only
    #AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html text/plain text/xml text/css text/javascript

    # Netscape 4.x has some problems...
    #BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4 gzip-only-text/html

    # Netscape 4.06-4.08 have some more problems
    #BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4\.0[678] no-gzip

    # MSIE masquerades as Netscape, but it is fine
    #BrowserMatch \bMSIE !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html

    # Don't compress images
    #SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI \.(?:gif|jpe?g|png)$ no-gzip dont-vary

    # Make sure proxies don't deliver the wrong content
    #Header append Vary User-Agent env=!dont-vary

</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_ssl.c>

############################################
## make HTTPS env vars available for CGI mode

    SSLOptions StdEnvVars

</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

############################################
## enable rewrites

    Options +FollowSymLinks
    RewriteEngine on

############################################
## you can put here your magento root folder
## path relative to web root

    #RewriteBase /magento/

############################################
## workaround for HTTP authorization
## in CGI environment

    #RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
    #RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
    #RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]


############################################
## always send 404 on missing files in these folders

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(media|skin|js)/

############################################
## Add trailing slashes to url's if they don't exist

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.html
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.php
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !price
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)/$
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1/ [L,R=301]

############################################
## Remove instances of multiple slashes

    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !=""
    RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]+\s//+(.*)\sHTTP/[0-9.]+$ [OR]
    RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]+\s(.*/)/+\sHTTP/[0-9.]+$
    RewriteRule .* http://%{HTTP_HOST}/%1 [R=301,L,NE]

############################################
## never rewrite for existing files, directories and links

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

############################################
## rewrite everything else to index.php

    RewriteRule .* index.php [L]

</IfModule>


############################################
## Prevent character encoding issues from server overrides
## If you still have problems, use the second line instead

    AddDefaultCharset Off
    #AddDefaultCharset UTF-8

<IfModule mod_expires.c>

############################################
## Add default Expires header
## http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#expires

    ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 year"

</IfModule>

############################################
## By default allow all access

    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all

############################################
## If running in cluster environment, uncomment this
## http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#etags

    #FileETag none

###########################################
```

Comment: How are the base url setup on the core config data ?

Comment: Thanks for the reply @YlgenGuxholli, they are setup as:

Unsecure Base URL: https://www.domain.com/
Secure Base URL: https://www.domain.com/

Comment: One thing I've just noticed is the BASE LINK URL is just: {{secure_base_url}} Does that need to have a / on the end of it too?

Answer (score 0):

Check on core_config data:
The base url secure and unsecure need to have a slash in the end:

> web/secure/base_url https://www.domain.com/
>
> web/unsecure/base_url https://www.domain.com/
>
> web/secure/base_js_url            {{secure_base_url}}js/
>   web/secure/base_link_url          {{secure_base_url}}
>   web/secure/base_media_url         {{secure_base_url}}media/
>   web/secure/base_skin_url          {{secure_base_url}}skin/
>
> web/unsecure/base_js_url            {{secure_base_url}}js/
>   web/unsecure/base_link_url          {{secure_base_url}}
>   web/unsecure/base_media_url         {{secure_base_url}}media/
>   web/unsecure/base_skin_url          {{secure_base_url}}skin/

If you are ok on this replace your htaccess with this one https://github.com/engineyard/magento-ce-1.9/blob/master/.htaccess.sample , i see this diff with your htaccess https://i.stack.imgur.com/IqSfU.jpg .

Let me know how it goes.